# MVC Passing Item Object from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First of all, I would like to show you my code.

Model:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MembershipType { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    var model = Session["members"] as Members;
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@if (Session["members"] != null)
{
    var ListOfItems = Session["members"] as List<Member>;
    foreach (var item in ListOfItems)
    {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink(item.RegisterDate.ToString(), "AddMemberTo", new { item })
```

As you can see from the code what I am trying to do is to pass the value of `Name`, `MembershipType` and `RegisterDate` from the View back to the Controller, so from Action I can retrieve the data. I send the data one by one but I am just wondering whether if its possible to send the object/item so from the controller I can access by Member.Name something like that

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so much it works, how do I commend you?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Your List, In View By Using Foreach

```
@foreach(var item in Model) {
// Use Model Items
 }
```

And Use `@Url.Action`

Like This :

```
 @foreach(var item in Model) {

 <a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id (item.YourParam },null)">
  //Set Display Value For Link                                
 </a>

     }
```